# printing lines where certain columns do not match, with awk

Tags: awk, matching

I have a tab separated file like this:

```
1       10502   C       T  
1       10506   C       T  
1       10567   G       A 
...
```

And I'm trying to print out all lines where `column 3 != column 4`, **excluding** the cases where `column 3 = C and column 4 = T`.

I tried

```
awk '{
if (($3 == $4) || ($3 == C && $4 == T) )
        next ;
else
        print $0; }'
```

but I'm not sure what's going wrong...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just fix your codes:

```
awk '($3 != $4) && !($3=="C" && $4=="T")' file
```

Answer (score -1):

this one-liner should work for your file:

```
awk '($3==$4)||($3 =="C"&&$4=="T"){next}1' input
```